# create table fails in loop (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sql script that creates tables for each db in my sql server. However it fails on one create table script. Eg the

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Mx_Poll_Tags]
```

command. What is wrong with this? I don't see it.

The weird part is when I one by one run the scripts in a query window they all work fine. Only is this particular proc it fails.

The error states:

> Msg 173, Level 15, State 1, Line 71
>   The definition for column 'Unit' must include a data type.

The create script is made by SQL Server itself by scripting an existing `Mx_Poll_Tags` table as `CreateTo`.

Does anyone see what the error is?

```
BEGIN
declare @proc nvarchar(max)
set @proc='if ''?'' like ''Client_%''

begin 
    use [?]
    print ''?''

    DROP TABLE [dbo].[ManualMetersInput]
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[ManualMeterActions]
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[ManualMeters]

        DROP TABLE [dbo].[MX_Poll]
    --DROP TABLE [dbo].[Mx_Poll_Tags]
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[MX_Poll_Info]
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[MX_Poll_Logs]
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[MX_Poll_QA]
    --DROP TABLE [dbo].[MX_Poll_Vars]

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ManualMeters]
    (
        [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [Ean] [varchar](max) NULL,
        [Period] [int] NULL,       
        [TagTable] [varchar](max) NULL,
        [TagTableId] [varchar](max) NOT NULL,
        [Overflow] [int] NULL,
        [TZ] [varchar](max) NULL,
    ) ON [PRIMARY] 

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ManualMetersInput]
    (
        [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [Timestamp] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
        [ManualMeterId] [int] NOT NULL,
        [Value] [decimal](18, 3) NOT NULL,
        [IsOverflow] [bit] NOT NULL,
        [ImportDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    ) ON [PRIMARY] 

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ManualMeterActions]
    (
        [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [ManualMeterId] [int] NOT NULL,
        [UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
        [Type] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MX_Poll]
    (
        [timestamp] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
        [localtimestamp] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    ) ON [PRIMARY] 

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MX_Poll_Info]
    (
        [timestamp] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
        [info] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MX_Poll_Logs]
    (
        [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [timestamp] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
        [Message] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MX_Poll_QA]
    (
        [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [timestamp] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
        [tag] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [QA] [int] NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY] 

    -- error here    
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Mx_Poll_Tags]
    (
        [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [Name] [nvarchar](800) NOT NULL,
        [Unit] [int] NOT NULL,
        [FieldName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
        [ScaleFromMin] [decimal](18, 3) NULL,
        [ScaleFromMax] [decimal](18, 3) NULL,
        [ScaleToMin] [decimal](18, 3) NULL,
        [ScaleToMax] [decimal](18, 3) NULL,
        [DeltaOfKwhCounter_Id] [int] NULL,
        [Visible] [int] NULL,
        [Type] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
        [Enable] [int] NULL,
        [Content] [int] NULL,
        [Quantity] [int] NULL,
        [Signal] [int] NULL,
        [SignalDescription] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [Connection] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [Cable] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [Comments] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [UsedForPrediction_0] [bit] NOT NULL,
        [RelatedToPrediction_0] [bit] NOT NULL,
        [CalculatedByPredictionNo] [int] NULL,
    ) ON [PRIMARY] 

end';

--print @proc;
exec sp_MSForEachDB @proc

END
GO
```

Comment: You do have the `drop table` statement commented out, though I would've expected a different error message...

Comment: Yeah, I commented it out because the table doesn't exist yet and else the drop gives an error. So that has nothing to do with the error in my question..

Comment: Based on the error message I would have expected there to be a text row like this `[Unit] NOT NULL,` where the data type was missing. Are you sure that the generated error message does not correspond to a query where this is indeed left off/omitted? Could happen as a copy/past error or maybe editing the query, something like that.

Comment: You could also take a look at the result of the `print @proc`. I can't really imagine you loose your datatype there, but it's an easy test.

Comment: Is unit a keyword by any chance? Something which the compiler sees differently in this case? Try units

Comment: There are tools which you can use to find out what query was actually executed, such as ApexSQL Log, or SQL Prompt (I think 'native' SQL profiler as well). If you can find the query, you can find the problem, I would think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try it with just creating that table?

Also, can you eliminate the "begin" and "end"? Based on this thread: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic808714-8-1.aspx

I don't have enough reputation to make this a comment.

**EDIT:**

By default, sys.sp_MSforeachdb @command1 has a parameter length of nvarchar(2000). Even though you're passing in a varchar(max), anything over 2000 is being truncated.

Comment: That doesn't help either. The weird part is when I copy the create script directly in de query window it does work. Only not when it's in that loop. I shall add that to the description of my problem.

Comment: I think it could be the length of your @proc variable. Can you reduce the proc down to just the exec sp_msforeach with your table. I believe by default, sp_msforeachdb has a max character length.

Comment: You are right, except the query would be truncated somewhere in the `CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MX_Poll_QA]` statement. So the error is in the wrong statement, it seems...

Comment: When I paste the query into word it is 2,184 characters.  The 2000th character is after `Comments` in the Mx_Poll_Tags Create Table statement.  Seems like this answer is valid.

Comment: @dcreight, I think so too, and it is easily tested, just remove everything except where the error occurs.

Comment: @ArthurDaniels; you're right. That was the issue. I've split it up and now it works as expected. Lesson learned :)